# Select columns based on value in row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select columns in a dataframe where the value in a row of that column meets a condition. 
My df looks like this.

```
                                      1           2           3
size                         135.000000   34.000000    1.000000
rel_size                       0.115582    0.029110    0.000856
mean_score_exam               60.903704   84.647059   64.000000
overall_mean_score_exam       68.234589   68.234589   68.234589
mean_score_non_exam          510.911111  643.117647  489.000000
overall_mean_score_non_exam  547.501712  547.501712  547.501712
pass_rate                      0.814815    1.000000    1.000000
overall_pass_rate              0.872432    0.872432    0.872432
derivation_from_pass_rate     -0.057617    0.127568    0.127568
```

Now I want to drop the columns where size is below 5.

```
                                      1           2
size                         135.000000   34.000000
rel_size                       0.115582    0.029110
mean_score_exam               60.903704   84.647059
overall_mean_score_exam       68.234589   68.234589
mean_score_non_exam          510.911111  643.117647
overall_mean_score_non_exam  547.501712  547.501712
pass_rate                      0.814815    1.000000
overall_pass_rate              0.872432    0.872432
derivation_from_pass_rate     -0.057617    0.127568
```

Seems like a very simple task, but I can't figure out how it is done
I've already tried to mask the columns like this

```
results.iloc[[0]] > 5

         0     1     2      3      4      5     6      7      8     9
size  True  True  True  False  False  False  True  False  False  True
```

but I don't now how to apply it to the dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
res = df.loc[:, df.loc["size"] >= 5]
```

**Option 2:**

```
res = df.drop(columns=df.columns[df.loc["size"] < 5])
```

**Result:**

```
In [25]: res
Out[25]:
                                      1           2
size                         135.000000   34.000000
rel_size                       0.115582    0.029110
mean_score_exam               60.903704   84.647059
overall_mean_score_exam       68.234589   68.234589
mean_score_non_exam          510.911111  643.117647
overall_mean_score_non_exam  547.501712  547.501712
pass_rate                      0.814815    1.000000
overall_pass_rate              0.872432    0.872432
derivation_from_pass_rate     -0.057617    0.127568
```

Comment: Huh, you're answering again, haven't seen your recently.

Comment: @U9-Forward, we have a public holiday here in Bavaria today, so I do have some free time ;)

Answer (score 0):

ideally you should transposed dataframe

```
df1_transposed = df1.T 
df1_transposed = df1_transposed[df1_transposed['size'] > 5]
```